# Angular2 tree checkbox with EventEmitter

Tags: javascript, angular

I have problems with tree view which has checkboxes on children. So, the problem is that I get nested stuff from event emitter. Please see screenshot and code.

This is my custom component where I have recursion and I just want to pass selected child or parent.

**Component**

```
import { Component, Input, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component ({
    selector: 'category-tree-view',
    template: `
    <ul class="tree">
        <li *ngFor="let category of treeData">
            <label class="control control--checkbox" *ngIf="hasCheckbox">
                <input type="checkbox" [checked]="category.checked" (change)="selectedCategory(category, $event)" />
                <div class="control__indicator"></div>
            </label>
            <span *ngIf="category.subcategories?.length" (click)="toggleChildren(category)" class="toggle">+</span>
            {{category.name}}
            <div class="tree-actions" *ngIf="hasActions">
                <button class="btn btn-link edit" (click)="editCategory(category)">
                  <i class="icon-admin-edit"></i>
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-link delete" (click)="deleteCategory(category)">
                  <i class="icon-admin-close"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            <category-tree-view [treeData]="category.subcategories" *ngIf="category.visible" (edit)="editCategory($event)" (delete)="deleteCategory($event)" [hasCheckbox]="hasCheckbox" (selected)="selectedCategory($event)" [hasActions]="hasActions"></category-tree-view>
        </li>
    </ul>
    `
})
export class ProductCategoryTreeView {
    @Input() treeData: any[];
    @Input() hasCheckbox: boolean = false;
    @Input() hasActions: boolean = false;
    @Output() edit = new EventEmitter();
    @Output() delete = new EventEmitter();
    @Output() selected = new EventEmitter();

    constructor() {}

    toggleChildren(node: any) {
        node.visible = !node.visible;
    }

    editCategory(category){
        this.edit.emit(category);
    }

    deleteCategory(category) {
        this.delete.emit(category);
    }

    selectedCategory(category, event) {
        this.selected.emit({category, event});
    }
}
```

This is what I have in my other html page, which is the different component, in this case, product-form.component.html

```
<category-tree-view [treeData]="categories" (edit)="editCategory($event)" (delete)="deleteCategory($event)" (selected)="selectCategory($event)" [hasCheckbox]="true"></category-tree-view>
```

And also I just have method in component product-form.component.ts

```
selectCategory(cat, event) {
    console.log(cat, event);
}
```

Here's the screenshot what I got when I console log that data.

[image: data from console.log]

Comment: You have a problem her. When you expand then collapse, the selected checkboxes disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try with below code and check if it works or not?

```
selectedCategory(category, event) {
    this.selected.emit(event);
}
```